# Location listing problem - crash in Android application

Tags: android

I am experimenting with locations and listviews. I am getting location results back and I am trying to create a listview of my locations results using the following code:

```
ListView locationList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        String[] items = new String[]{};

        try {
            Geocoder geocoder       =   new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses =   geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 5);
            address_textview.setText( ""+addresses );
            
            Address[] addresses_array       =   new Address[addresses.size()];
            addresses.toArray(addresses_array);
            
            for( int i = 0; i < addresses_array.length; i++ ){
                items[i]    =   addresses_array[i].getPostalCode();
            }
                   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    =   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, items);
        locationList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My problem is, when I try to write into my items array (`items[i] = addresses_array[i].getPostalCode()`)  in the forloop, my application crashes.

Comment: Please, post the logcat output.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `items` as an array and allocate it as zero size. Try e.g. a `List<string>` instead (and adjust your Adapter, or use `List<T>.toArray`).